# Log::Log4perl::Config::DOMConfigurator

Tags: perl

I am writing Perl script. In that I have to read log4j.xml file from perl and log messages into specific queues. I read that [DOMConfigurator](https://metacpan.org/module/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aConfig%3a%3aDOMConfigurator) can do that. Can anyone provide me the sample code to read log4j.xml file from perl and log the messages using [DOMConfigurator](https://metacpan.org/module/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aConfig%3a%3aDOMConfigurator)? Is there any other way in Perl to read xml based log4j to log messages?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Log::Log4perl::Config::DOMConfigurator](http://p3rl.org/Log%3a%3aLog4perl%3a%3aConfig%3a%3aDOMConfigurator#SEE-ALSO) documentation references the test files [`t/038XML-DOM1.t`](https://metacpan.org/source/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.34/t/038XML-DOM1.t), [`t/039XML-DOM2.t`](https://metacpan.org/source/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.34/t/039XML-DOM2.t) as code examples.